# JAXB how to access nested list

Tags: java, xml, jaxb2

I have the following XML and need to obtain the details from each 'Client'. So that's for each 'Client' I need to get each 'Usage' and each attribute in turn.
How would I do this using JAXB? Thanks

```
<Bob xmlns="gdfgdfg">
    <Alice>
        <Rob>dsdsdsd</Rob>
        <Mike>fdgdfg</<Mike>>
        <Pete>dfgdfg</Pete>
        <UsageList>
            <Client id="1">
                <Usage cat1="100002" dog1="1000020000" fish1="1"
                    mouse1="2" beginTime="24-09-2015 12:29:29 +0100" endTime="24-09-2015 12:29:29 +0100"
                    ant1="aaaaa" snake1="1" errcode="1" />
                <Usage cat1="1000230" dog1="10000560000" fish1="1"
                    mouse1="2" beginTime="24-09-2015 12:29:29 +0100" endTime="24-09-2015 12:29:29 +0100"
                    ant1="aaaaa" snake1="1" errcode="1" />
                <Usage cat1="100001" dog1="4656545465" fish1="1"
                    mouse1="2" beginTime="24-09-2015 12:29:29 +0100" endTime="24-09-2015 12:29:29 +0100"
                    ant1="aaaaa" snake1="1" errcode="0" />
                <Usage cat1="100001" dog1="4656545465" fish1="1"
                    mouse1="2" beginTime="24-09-2015 12:29:44 +0100" endTime="24-09-2015 12:29:44 +0100"
                    ant1="aaaaa" snake1="1" errcode="0" />
                <Usage cat1="100002" dog1="1000020000" fish1="1"
                    mouse1="2" beginTime="24-09-2015 12:29:44 +0100" endTime="24-09-2015 12:29:44 +0100"
                    ant1="aaaaa" snake1="1" errcode="1" />
                <Usage cat1="100000" dog1="10000000000" fish1="1"
                    mouse1="2" beginTime="24-09-2015 12:24:28 +0100" endTime="24-09-2015 12:24:28 +0100"
                    ant1="aaaaa" snake1="1" errcode="1" />
            </Client>
            <Client id="2">
                <Usage cat1="100003" dog1="465546" fish1="1"
                    mouse1="2" beginTime="24-09-2015 12:29:44 +0100" endTime="24-09-2015 12:29:44 +0100"
                    ant1="aaaaa" snake1="1" errcode="0" />
                <Usage cat1="100005" dog1="10000000000" fish1="1"
                    mouse1="2" beginTime="24-09-2015 12:29:44 +0100" endTime="24-09-2015 12:29:44 +0100"
                    ant1="aaaaa" snake1="1" errcode="1" />
                <Usage cat1="100003" dog1="465546" fish1="1"
                    mouse1="2" beginTime="24-09-2015 12:29:29 +0100" endTime="24-09-2015 12:29:29 +0100"
                    ant1="aaaaa" snake1="1" errcode="0" />
                <Usage cat1="100004" dog1="1002300000" fish1="1"
                    mouse1="2" beginTime="24-09-2015 12:29:29 +0100" endTime="24-09-2015 12:29:29 +0100"
                    ant1="aaaaa" snake1="1" errcode="1" />
                <Usage cat1="100005" dog1="10000000000" fish1="1"
                    mouse1="2" beginTime="24-09-2015 12:29:29 +0100" endTime="24-09-2015 12:29:29 +0100"
                    ant1="aaaaa" snake1="1" errcode="1" />
                <Usage cat1="100004" dog1="1002300000" fish1="1"
                    mouse1="2" beginTime="24-09-2015 12:29:44 +0100" endTime="24-09-2015 12:29:44 +0100"
                    ant1="aaaaa" snake1="1" errcode="1" />
            </Client>
            <Client id="3">
                <Usage cat1="100007" dog1="5463453" fish1="1"
                    mouse1="3" beginTime="24-09-2015 12:29:44 +0100" endTime="24-09-2015 12:29:44 +0100"
                    ant1="aaaaa" snake1="1" errcode="1" />
                <Usage cat1="100006" dog1="122113231" fish1="1"
                    mouse1="2" beginTime="24-09-2015 12:29:29 +0100" endTime="24-09-2015 12:29:29 +0100"
                    ant1="aaaaa" snake1="1" errcode="1" />
                <Usage cat1="100007" dog1="5463453" fish1="1"
                    mouse1="3" beginTime="24-09-2015 12:29:29 +0100" endTime="24-09-2015 12:29:29 +0100"
                    ant1="aaaaa" snake1="1" errcode="1" />
                <Usage cat1="100006" dog1="122113231" fish1="1"
                    mouse1="2" beginTime="24-09-2015 12:29:44 +0100" endTime="24-09-2015 12:29:44 +0100"
                    ant1="aaaaa" snake1="1" errcode="1" />
            </Client>
        </UsageList>
    </Alice>
</Bob>
```

I have my jaxb generated class which contains:

```
public List<UsageListType> getUsageList() {
            if (usageList == null) {
                usageList = new ArrayList<UsageListType>();
            }
            return this.usageList;
        }
```

but not sure how this helps me access each attribute from each element.

Comment: Look at the `UsageListType` class.